# How to load library defined symbols to a specified location?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, glibc, elf

The test is on Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit, with `gcc` 4.6.3.

Basically I am doing some binary manipulation work on ELF binaries, and what I have to do now is to assemble a assembly program and guarantee the libc symbols are loaded to a predefined address by me.

Let me elaborate it in an simple example.

Suppose in the original code, libc symbols `stdout@GLIBC_2.0` is used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* fout = stdout;
    fprintf( fout, "hello\n" );
}
```

When I compile it and check the symbol address using these commands:

```
gcc main.c
readelf -s a.out | grep stdout
```

I got this:

```
0804a020     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 stdout@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
0804a020     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 stdout@@GLIBC_2.0
```

and the `.bss` section is like this:

```
  readelf -S a.out | grep bss
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          0804a020 001014 00000c 00  WA  0   0 32
```

Now what I am trying to do is to load the `stdout` symbol in a predefined address, so I did this:

```
echo "stdout = 0x804a024;" > symbolfile
gcc -Wl,--just-symbols=symbolfile  main.c
```

Then when I check the `.bss` section and symbol `stdout`, I got this:

```
 [25] .bss              NOBITS          0804a014 001014 000008 00  WA  0   0  4


4: 0804a024     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS stdout
49: 0804a024     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS stdout
```

1. It seems that I didn't successfully load the symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.0`, but just a wired `stdout`. (I tried to write `stdout@@GLIBC_2.0` in `symbolfile`, but it can't compile... )
2. It seems that as I didn't make it, the beginning address of `.bss` section has also changed, which makes the address of `stdout` symbol in a non-section area. During runtime, it throws a segmentation fault when loading from `0x804a024`.

Could anyone help me on how to successfully load the library symbol at a predefined address? Thanks!

Comment: you can use "" to write stdout@GLIBC_2.0 in your linker script. but i think you must set it's attribute like Ndx, .. correctly. I am still researching about this when I find something, I tell you.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani , thank you buddy! Let me have a try!