# Reuse symbols in disassembling/reassembling a C++ program

Tags: c, assembly, elf, symbols, undefined-symbol

it's me again. I am working on a tool can that disassemble/reassemble stripped binaries and now I am sucked in a (external) symbol reuse issue.

The test is on 32-bit Linux x86 platform.

Suppose I am working on a C++ program, in the `GCC` compiler produced assembly code, there exists some instructions like this:

```
call    _ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev
movl    _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE+4, %ebx
movb    $0, 312(%esp)
movl    _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE+8, %ecx
....
```

Please pay special attention to symbol `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE`.

After the compilation, suppose I get an `unstripped` binary, and i checked this symbol like this:

```
readelf -s a.out | grep "_ZTTSt14basic"
69: 080a7390    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   27 _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)
72: 080a7220    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   27 _ZTTSt14basic_ofstreamIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)
705: 080a7220    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   27 _ZTTSt14basic_ofstreamIcS
1033: 080a7390    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   27 _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS
```

See, this is my first question, **why the name of symbol `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE` modified to `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS` and `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)` ?**

What is `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)` though?

Then I stripped the binary like this:

```
strip a.out
readelf -s a.out | grep "_ZTTSt14basic"
69: 080a7390    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   27 _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)
72: 080a7220    16 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   27 _ZTTSt14basic_ofstreamIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)
```

Then after I disassemble the binary, and the corresponding disassembled assembly instructions are :

```
 8063ee7:       e8 84 54 fe ff          call   8049370 <_ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev@plt>
 8063eec:       8b 1d 94 73 0a 08       mov    0x80a7394,%ebx
 8063ef2:       c6 84 24 38 01 00 00    movb   $0x0,0x138(%esp)
 8063ef9:       00
 8063efa:       8b 0d 98 73 0a 08       mov    0x80a7398,%ecx
```

At this point we can figure out that 0x80a7394 equals to `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE+4`.

In order to reuse these instructions, I modified the code:

```
call _ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev
mov _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS+4,%ebx
movb $0x0,0x138(%esp)
mov _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS+8,%ecx
```

And did some update like these (please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355292/how-to-load-library-defined-symbols-to-a-specified-location) for reference):

```
echo ""_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)" = 0x080a7390;" > symbolfile
g++ -Wl,--just-symbols=symbolfile  final.s

readelf -s a.out | grep "_ZTTSt14basic"

3001: 080a7390     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   27 _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS
8412: 080a7390     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS
```

I debugged the newly produced binary, and to my surprise, in the newly produced binary, symbol `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS` does not get any value after the function call of `_ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev`, while in the original binary, after the function call, `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS` do get some memory address referring to library section.  Which means:

```
call _ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev
mov _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS+4,%ebx  <--- %ebx gets zero!
movb $0x0,0x138(%esp)
mov _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS+8,%ecx  <--- %ecx gets zero!
```

I must state that in these lines of the original binary, registers %ebx and %ecx both gets some addresses referring to the libc section.

This is my second question, why does symbol `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcS` didn't get any value after function call `_ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev`? I also tried with symbol name `_ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE`. But that does not work also.

Am I clear enough? Could anyone save my ass? thank you!

Comment: You need to use `-W` option to `readelf` otherwise it will truncate output.

Comment: @Jester, you are right..!